# linearly interpolate gaps in a time-series array with missing values at weekends

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays created from reading a `CSV` file, that contains a date and a stock closing price. I want to interpolate the data so that it 'fills in' the gaps where there is no data at weekends and can't work out how.

The data is just in a `numpy` array with dates like `(0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,14....)` and corresponding prices, so a list of **`( Timestamp, value )`** pairs like this:

```
[(0.0, -0.39333333333333442), (1.0, -0.11333333333333329),
 (4.0, -0.17333333333333556), (5.0, -0.0033333333333338544),
 (6.0, -0.023333333333333428), (7.0, 0.046666666666666856),
 (8.0, 0.13666666666666671), (11.0, 0.12666666666666515),
 (12.0, 0.39666666666666472)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you having problems with that you can't work out how? You're basically pointing yourself to the correct solution (look up "numpy interpolate").

Comment: I currently have values in a list of (Timestamp, value) like this:

[(0.0, -0.39333333333333442), (1.0, -0.11333333333333329), (4.0, -0.17333333333333556), (5.0, -0.0033333333333338544), (6.0, -0.023333333333333428), (7.0, 0.046666666666666856), (8.0, 0.13666666666666671), (11.0, 0.12666666666666515), (12.0, 0.39666666666666472)]

I have looked up both numpy interpolation and scipy interpolation but can't figure out how to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) gives some very good examples (visual even) to show you how to interpolate the data.

Applying that method to your data, gives you this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(0.0, -0.39333333333333442), (1.0, -0.11333333333333329),
            (4.0, -0.17333333333333556), (5.0, -0.0033333333333338544),
            (6.0, -0.023333333333333428), (7.0, 0.046666666666666856),
            (8.0, 0.13666666666666671), (11.0, 0.12666666666666515),
            (12.0, 0.39666666666666472)])

all_dates = np.arange(a[0,0], a[-1,0]+1) # assuming your 'dates' are always integers
lin_interp = np.interp(all_dates, a[:,0], a[:,1])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(all_dates, lin_interp, 'go:', ms=10)
plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], 'bs:')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Remark that this is only a simple linear interpolation. There is no guarantee that the stockprices during those weekend days were like the ones shown by the interpolation.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much